# How to write the result of a calculation to a file in Prolog?

Tags: file, text, prolog, evaluation

I wish to export the result of a calculation to a file of text in Prolog, attempting the following:

I compile the following program **test.pl**:

```
write_to_file(File, Text) :-
   open(File, write, Stream),
   write(Stream, Text), nl,
   close(Stream).
```

I do the following:

`Y is 2**10000.`

And finally:

`write_to_file('test.txt',Y).`

But the contents of the file test.txt are as follows:

`_306`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reuse a variable in different calls to the Prolog top-level, you need to prefix that variable with the `$` character.  For your example:

```
?- Y is 2**10000.
?- write_to_file('text.txt', $Y).
```

This is not needed if you make the two calls at one, using Prolog conjunction (`,`):

```
?- Y is 2**10000, write_to_file('text.txt', Y).
```